# How do you use Tailwind to generate a CSS file with variables?

Tags: tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind to generate [`rfui.css`](https://rfui.deno.dev/rfui.css) by doing:

```
./tailwindcss -i static/app.css -o static/rfui.css --minify
```

As you [can see](https://rfui.deno.dev/rfui.css), there are some CSS variables in use. However, they aren't always used. For example, they aren't used for the color palate, and I'd love to let users customize the look and feel by defining their own color palate by setting CSS variables in that file.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to set CSS variables for colors. As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-css-variables):

> If you’d like to define your colors as CSS variables, you’ll need to define those variables as just the color channels if you want them to work with the [opacity modifier syntax](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-color#changing-the-opacity):
>
> **Define your CSS variables as channels with no color space function**
>
> main.css
>
> ```css
> @tailwind base;
> @tailwind components;
> @tailwind utilities;
>
> @layer base {
>   :root {
>     --color-primary: 255 115 179;
>     --color-secondary: 111 114 185;
>     /* ... */
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> […]
>
> Then define your colors in your configuration file, being sure to include the color space you’re using, and the special `<alpha-value>` placeholder that Tailwind will use to inject the alpha value when using an opacity modifier:
>
> tailwind.config.js
>
> ```js
> /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
> module.exports = {
>   theme: {
>     colors: {
>       // Using modern `rgb`
>       primary: 'rgb(var(--color-primary) / <alpha-value>)',
>       secondary: 'rgb(var(--color-secondary) / <alpha-value>)',
>
>       // Using modern `hsl`
>       primary: 'hsl(var(--color-primary) / <alpha-value>)',
>       secondary: 'hsl(var(--color-secondary) / <alpha-value>)',
>
>       // Using legacy `rgba`
>       primary: 'rgba(var(--color-primary), <alpha-value>)',
>       secondary: 'rgba(var(--color-secondary), <alpha-value>)',
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> When defining your colors this way, make sure that the format of your CSS variables is correct for the color function you are using. You’ll want to use spaces if using the modern [space-separated syntax](https://css-tricks.com/the-expanding-gamut-of-color-on-the-web/#aa-a-tale-of-new-syntaxes), and commas if using legacy functions like `rgba` or `hsla`:
>
> main.css
>
> ```css
> @tailwind base;
> @tailwind components;
> @tailwind utilities;
>
> @layer base {
>   :root {
>     /* For rgb(255 115 179 / <alpha-value>) */
>     --color-primary: 255 115 179;
>
>     /* For hsl(198deg 93% 60% / <alpha-value>) */
>     --color-primary: 198deg 93% 60%;
>
>     /* For rgba(255, 115, 179, <alpha-value>) */
>     --color-primary: 255, 115, 179;
>   }
> }
> ```